# PHP - Cron Job Run At Specific Date & time

Tags: php, cron

How to identify that cron job will run on specific Date&Time with help of cron expression Only

Comment: Hello.. eg :- If user Enter cron experssion :-*/2 5 * * * And Start Date time :-14 March 2013 00:00::00 End Time :- 15 March 2013 00:00::00 then how to identify how many time cron job will exceute  & at what date&time within start & end time limit

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Replace the `*` with the values you need.

Answer (score 9):

Structure for cron job parameters

```
Minutes [0-59]
    |   Hours [0-23]
    |   |   Days [1-31]
    |   |   |   Months [1-12]
    |   |   |   |   Days of the Week [Numeric, 0-6]
    |   |   |   |   |
    *   *   *   *   * home/path/to/command/the_command.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use apache control panel, refer to it. usually it has a `cron job` section with good help and example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start with the crontab time/date values and then see a list of future run-times try the cron sandbox at [dataphyx.](http://www.dataphyx.com)